# Using MaterialStatePropertyAll in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
OutlinedButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
            padding: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 30)),
            shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)))),
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text('Text'))
```

For example, we have a button as in the code below. I need to use MaterialStatePropertyAll to give properties to this button. Do I have to write MaterialStatePropertyAll when I attribute the button each time? Can't we just write this in one go and collect all the OutlinedButton properties under MaterialStatePropertyAll?

Answer (score 0):

You can define this in `MaterialApp's theme` and all your `OutlinedButton` get that automatically:

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
      style: ButtonStyle(
          padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(
              EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 30)),
          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)))),
    ),
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: ...,
)
```

then use it in every class that has that material as parent like this:

```
OutlinedButton(
      style: Theme.of(context).outlinedButtonTheme.style,
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('Text'),
)
```

Comment: @ckot was it what you want?